# How can I create a shared URL pointing to an achor in a Google Docs document's TOC?

Tags: google-docs, sharing, url, google-drive-sharing

I have a Google Docs document which I share with other users through the `Share through hyperlink` feature.

On that document, on every heading level 1, 2... I use `Format > Paragraph style > Title 1, 2...` for creating pretty formatted titles and at the same time automatically building the TOC.

[image]

I'd like to generate an hyperlink which allows me to share the document but also that the user opening the document lands directly on one of the headings. Like a traditional web URL with #anchor.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, when you click the header in the table of contents you'll see a string starting with `heading` appended to the URL like so:

[image: example of header append to URL]

Share out the URL with the `#heading` string at the end and when users open the doc it will open directly to that heading.

Comment: Nice! Scroll position isn't very precise but it's working. Thank you!